# limit of integral exists implies existence of convergent improper integral, provided $f$ is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis

I encounter with the following statement:

Let $f$ be any real-valued function. If f is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and $\lim_{c\to\infty}\int_{-c}^{c}f(x) dx$ exists and is finite, then $f$ has convergent improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) dx$.

I think this statement is false, but have not come up with a counterexample. Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: $f(x)=cx$ where $c\not =0$ and is constant

Answer (score 0):

Your question is related to the concept of principal value. Usually, one defines an integral of the form $\int_{-\infty}^\infty(...)$ to be convergent if both $\int_{-\infty}^a$ and $\int_a^\infty(...)$ are convergent in the usual sense. However, sometimes the weaker notion of "principal value" is used, where you look at the limits of proper integrals over symmetric intervals, like the one that you mention.
Then, a function like $f(x)=x/(1+x^2)$, which is not integrable in the usual sense, would have an improper integral in the sense of principal value, clearly equal to zero because of the symmetry. This is denoted as
$$
\textrm{V. p.}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x}{x^2+1}\,dx=0
$$